# How much to eat and drink during a 50km ride?

Tags: training, hydration, nutrition

I want to try a [50 km ride](http://www.rideforheart.ca) for the first time, to be completed continuously one morning.

The most I've even done before is an 18 km (70 minute) each way commute (out in the morning and back in the evening).

When I commute I eat (breakfast, and late afternoon snack) before I ride, but I eat and drink nothing during the ride.

I guess that the difference between that and a 50 km ride is that, on the multi-hour ride, I ought to eat or drink something on/during the ride to replenish? How much should I eat and drink then, and when? Should I expect to take rest stops, and/or to go more slowly on average?

I'm wary because I think I've read that glycogen depletes at around the 2-hour mark, whereas my longest continuous ride to date has has been only 80 minutes.

Comment: Chris, that's only barely more than riding to work and straight back home again. Assuming you already wear cycling knicks and have a water bottle and puncture kit, I can't see any need to worry. I regularly jump from 10km each way every day to 100km/day cycle touring with no training or body prep (my preparation is all about getting my bike and camping gear ready). The first day or two are a bit lazy (60-80km) but after that I just ride. Admittedly a big day at the start of the tour is 120km, and a month or two later it's 200km, but 50km... just make sure you have breakfast before you start.

Comment: See also [Diet - What should one eat while cycling?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2225).

Comment: @moz I don't have cycling knicks nor have a water bottle nor puncture kit (I don't think I need a puncture kit: it'll be a well-supported ride). Also 50 km in a day wouldn't worry me. I think we're supposed to finish it all in one go though, in the morning, then they reopen the road to cars.

Comment: I took a look at the ride route online. It looks as if the organization is providing food and rest stops. With your daily commute, you should have no problem with this ride, especially if you eat and drink at each rest stop. "Water, fresh fruit and healthy snacks are provided at each of the rest stations, and at the finish line."

Comment: Also see http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2894/most-suitable-and-tasty-ride-food

Comment: @ChrisW: Just to chime in. I did the 75 km Ride for Heart 2 years in a row. My daily commute when I was in Toronto was 2.5 km each way on a hybrid bike. I wasn't going for a record time and so I finished it in 3.5 hours. The food + water along the rest stops was very refreshing and was all I needed. My only training otherwise was my usual gym sessions, nothing special. You should be fine and enjoy the ride! Hopefully this year it's actually sunny. I'm no longer in Toronto but I'd do it again if I was.

Comment: @ChrisW: I'd have some answers for a multi-hour bike ride. 50k/30mi  is not that. I did 50K after a breakfast of oatmeal yesterday. Nothing special, 50K, stop and go, 2 hours. Also, I'm an old guy.

Comment: @wdypdx22 It takes me 75 minutes to go 18 km (including some traffic lights etc) when I commute: which, assuming I keep the same average speed over the longer distance, would be 210 minutes per 50 km: i.e. 3.5 hours, or nearly twice your time.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong...your particular ride may take "you" several hours. For some of us, a 50km ride is not multi-hours. For some of us 50km is just a workout. Seriously, for me, staying at or under 14.5 km/hr is very difficult. I just can't go that slow...except for steep hills...

Comment: @wdypdx22 - 14.5 km/hr must be my average speed, not my maximum. I don't know how much faster it will be on a path without stops and without traffic. I'm not much overweight: 182 cm / 76 kg (6'0" / 168 lb), which is the middle of the recommended BMI, not obese. I'm nearly 50 and this is my first good bike. I don't know what the main reason is for my going so ridiculously slowly: traffic? clothing? lung capacity? laziness? metabolism? temperature? My time to do the route has barely decreased since I started, two months ago: about 80 minutes on my first ride, and still about 70 minutes or more.

Comment: @wdypdx22 - My commute route is 6 km of bike lane and bike path, with about 4 stops; 4.5 km of back streets with frequent stop signs (e.g. one every block); 2 km of fast bike lane with maybe 3 stops at traffic lights;  1.5 km of road with a bad surface; 4.5 km more or less up hill (gaining maybe 60 m elevation).

Comment: @ChrisW - Your commute is not ridiculously slow. It just sounds like traffic, stop-and-go, etc. On my commute, I'm right there with you. Otherwise, I think you'll be pleasantly surprised at how quickly you ride the upcoming 50K.

Comment: Renamed to avoid confusion with [this question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/multi-hour-ride-nutrition).

Comment: You know that cycling advocacy is making some headway when they can shut down the DVP for a charity ride.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

50km isn't that enormous of a distance - and especially for someone who does 18km twice a day.  It sounds like your current pace would have you completing that in about three hours.  I'd bring a snack or two if you're worried about being peckish, but unless you're going all-out for a personal record or you skip breakfast you should have no issues.  Just keep turning the pedals, make sure you drink some water, and feel free to take a 5-minute stretch and snack break if you're feeling tired.

Comment: My normal ride is just over an hour. I suppose this one will be about four hours, so definitely a 'personal record'.

Comment: I mean in terms of pace.  You'll use more energy and burn more calories if you try to hammer out a fast time.

Comment: @ChrisW: 50k is not that problematic with your total ODO. I wouldn't worry too much about distance. But your pace is obviously rather low. If you'll participate on that event, be prepared that speeds may be higher than your average. This means that you won't need 4 hours for the ride. You'll see. You'll feel quite some adrenaline at start. Which is good. First 1/4 of the way will just slip away in a short time. Make sure you drink every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 13):

This link "[Quick note: Eating is the key to long distance biking](http://www.wirewd.com/bike/blog/eating_long_distance_short/)" says,

> If you don't eat, you have an hour, maybe two, of energy stored up.

Fortunately it's prescriptive too, saying,

> And what should these calories be?
>   Well, something easy on your stomach
>   and fairly light. There are special
>   sporting-related products that are
>   generally right around 100 calories
>   and super-easy on your stomach, but
>   you don't have to go overboard. A
>   piece of fruit or some candy or even a
>   can of soda will work just fine. Just
>   try to keep it around 100-200 calories
>   maximum per hour.

... so that answers that: only about 100-200 calories an hour. Apparently you don't try to to keep up with the approx 500 calorie/hour rate at which you're expending calories.

As for what, [this](http://readytoride.biz/?p=238) recommends bike-specific stuff based on maltodextrin, brand name "Hammer", and says that the body can't absorb more than 200-300 calories an hour - but that's for a multi-day ride.

Whereas [this](http://kentsbike.blogspot.com/2009/10/what-long-distance-cyclists-really-eat.html) recommends:

- Junk food (donuts, gummi bears, etc.)
- Chocolate
- Nuts (or peanuts)
- Olives (salty, light-weight, and high-calorie: though I'll guess slow to absorb)
- A Subway sandwich but without any hot/spicy components
- Ice tea (sugar and caffeine)
- Fruit (bananas, banana chips, fig bars)
- Cereal bars

---

To answer the "[how much to drink?](http://www.google.ca/#q=cycling+how+much+drink)" question:

- [This](http://www.suite101.com/content/more-on-hydration-for-cycling-a16979) says, that 'one litre per hour' is on the high side, that that's for endurance not recreational rides.
- [This](http://www.articledashboard.com/Article/How-Much-Water-You-Should-Drink-When-Cycling-for-Optimum-Performance/1735109) says 16 oz / 45 minutes (~ 0.63 l/h).
- [This](http://www.livestrong.com/article/9384-stay-hydrated-cycling/) says 28 oz / hour (~ 0.83 l/h).
- [This](http://www.maskedflowerimages.com/articles/bicycling.html) says a couple of big swallows every 15 minutes.

One of those articles also says that you thirst after dehydrating 1% and suffer when you drop 5%. I weigh 77 kg so I suppose I'm 46 litres of water, so 1% is about half a litre. If I don't drink when riding then (if I ought to be replenishing up to a litre an hour) that predicts that I'd be thirsty (1%) within 1/2 hour or an hour, and suffering (5%) within 2 1/2 to 4 hours.

[This](http://www.usatf.org/groups/Coaches/library/2007/hydration/ProperHydrationForDistanceRunning.pdf) says that "Sports drinks have low-sodium levels in order to be appetizing to the general public" and suggests 500 to 700 mg of sodium per litre. Salt is 40% sodium, so that's 1.2 to 1.8 grams of salt per litre.

1.2 g salt is about 1/2 cc or 1/5 tsp (per litre of water), which is less than I'd imagined.

Comment: wdypdx22 suggested Clif bars as a ride snack.

Comment: And also said any energy bar of choice. For a 50km _supported_ ride in relatively easy terrain, you really don't need to be terribly concerned about ride nutrition. You really don't need gels and powders for a ride this short and if you go with the _Hammer Nutrition_ products just stick to the Hammer bars. And, you're getting all the training you need with your daily commute.

Comment: For hydration, just sip through a large water bottle every hour which is typically in the neighborhood of .7 l/h. If a hot day, a bit more. On the other hand, don't gulp down an entire bottle every hour. But seriously, you're going to do just _great!_ Your ride has 4 supported rest stops along the way, so there's no way that you're going to need to worry about glycogen depletion or dehydration.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answers provided thus far....

<strike>- *Moz suggests:*_ *Cycling knicks, water bottles, and a puncture kit*. Excellent advice. And, I assume that Moz means padded cycling shorts. The puncture kit is also good advice since you might get a flat between stops. Water bottles? Seriously, who can cycle without water bottles?
  - *The test ride:* Equip yourself with some calories and at least 2 water bottles and the puncture kit. The puncture kit is good since no one will be out there to help you on the test ride.
  - *The ride.* You have no worries.</strike>

And @Chris -- You're already building up endurance miles. You'll be fine. You'll sail through the 50K with no problems. The 50K Ride is not "long distance".

Anyhow, the real answer depends upon your current cycling fitness level. So, *the real answer* will be quite different between a beginner, vs, a fitness-cyclist coming out of the winter doldrum, vs, a racer; and etc...

The ride you intend to do in June is a *supported* 50k ride. I looked at your ride map and there are 4 rest stops along the way. You really don't need to worry much about hydration or consuming enough calories. Take advantage of the rest stops and you'll be totally fine. You already have a good start with your daily commute. My guess is that you'll do much better than you think, since you won't need to worry about stop-lights, etc.

Comment: "Seriously, who can cycle without water bottles?" - Someone who's never ridden more than 75 minutes, and (so far) always at temperatures below a maximum of about 15C.

Comment: Well, thanks. I'd better get some. The weather's changing, getting hotter. Today's the first day that I found riding in jeans seemed a little too warm.

Answer (score 2):

Just prepare properly the day before. Drink loads of fluid (water) and eat some carbs (pasta etc) with chicken  and vegetables. For breakfast, eat brown bread with loads of jam, some porridge and tea/coffee with sugar. 45 minutes before cycle eat a banana and you should be continuously  drinking (sipping) water. During the cycle eat a small bar (energy from chocolate) and some fluid. You will be grand and enjoy the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

30 miles isn't enough that you should be worrying about eating and drinking. Even at a slow, sustained 15mph, just bring a bottle of gatorade and a bottle of water. Drink gatorade the first hour, then water the second (the ride will be over by the time you'd feel any extra energy from the second bottle).

Maybe have a small snack beforehand. A granola bar or something else that's light.