# Couch to Century

Tags: training, century

Due to injury I've got to take a little time off from biking.  My physical therapist recommended doing a "couch to marathon" program when I'm feeling better to get me back into the swing of things.  But, being that I would rather ride a bike, are there any "couch to century" programs out there?  The reason my knee problem has persisted is because I get too excited when it feels a little better and I overdo the biking right out the gate resulting in re-injury.  So, I'd like something that takes me up to a century at a slow pace, maybe over a few months.

EDIT: In the spirit of less chatty answers, maybe a link to a specific training program would be nice.

Comment: Any way to make this question solicit less chatty answers? It's a valid question, but I can see a lot of answers like "you should try X" showing up.

Comment: "...My physical therapist recommended..." So, I gather that you intend to ignore the physical therapist and get advice here?

Comment: @wdypdx22: My injury is a running injury during marathon training and my physical therapist was just telling me I could start running again via a couch to marathon program once the pain goes away.  He also said there is no issue with me biking once the pain subsides.  Not ignoring his advice, just trading couch to marathon for couch to century.

Comment: One thing that can't be emphasized too much, with a knee injury, is ***gear down!***  Also, make sure your seat is high enough -- should be about as high as you can place it without needing to rock side-to-side to pedal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to answer this as a true couch to century with a general plan. You can write books on this stuff. There *have* been books written on this stuff.

You have three major goals for a successful century:

1. Get the raw fitness needed to keep the pedals going for 6+ hours.
2. Figure out how much you need to eat while going for the entire thing.
3. Do the above without getting any stress injuries.

**Off the Couch**
You are off the couch. You have a bike, old, new, mountain bike, road bike, it doesn't matter. If you've never ridden, get something cheap so you're not out much money if this isn't for you. You have at least one pair of cycling shorts, gloves and a helmet. The goals here are just to ride around. Don't go terribly hard, find some scenic routes, avoid steep hills if possible. Most importantly, work on pedalling smoothly. Nice circles with the feet.

Each week, try to get in three one hour rides.

**Building up**
Make your way up to 4 rides per week. Three shorter ones and one longer one, maybe up to 2 hours. On your favourite loop, you'll see your average times slowly dropping. You are still not trying to ride really hard. When you get to the point that your weekly 2 hour ride isn't leaving you wasted for the day and the century still seems like a good idea, it's time for the next phase.

**Really Starting**
Get a road or touring bike. Mountain bikes were fine up until this point, but unless your century is off road, you will want a real road bike. **[Get fitted by a pro](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3549/bike-fitting-experiences)**, this is possibly your single biggest injury prevention mechanism. Get [clipless pedals](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/827/what-should-i-look-for-in-clipless-pedals-and-shoes). Practice with them on the grass until you stop falling over.

The following sections can be repeated as needed. I did not get to 'month 3' for at least a year. Listen to your body.

**Month 1**
If you commute by bike, everything other than the 'long' ride could be 2 shorter rides, always work on smooth pedalling. For the longer ride, bring a small snack and [practice eating](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3532/how-much-to-eat-and-drink-during-a-50km-ride).
Week 1-2: 3x1 hour, 1x2 hours
Week 3: 3x1 hour, 1x3 hours
Week 4: 4x1 hour

**Month 2**
Once per week, on the one hour ride, spend about 20 minutes in a flatter section riding harder. You want to hit a pace that's uncomfortable, but when 20 minutes is up, you can keep riding. You're not killing yourself here. You should be breathing hard, but if you really had to, you could go at that pace for an hour or more. This will take practice.

The longer rides now provide the constant threat of bonking. Try out gels, sports drinks, bananas, cold roasted potatoes and see what is palatable for you on the ride. Most organized  centuries have food stops, so you need to know before you do it if the food they are going to provide will agree with you. Aim for ~300 calories per hour, but listen to your body.

Week 1-2: 3x1 hour, 1x3 hours
Week 3: 3x1 hour, 1x4 hours
Week 4: 4x1 hour

**Month 3**
Once per week on a one hour ride, do 2 of those 20 minute efforts with a 10 minute gap in the middle. Again, you're not killing yourself on these. It's uncomfortable, your legs are telling you that it would be nice to slow down a bit, but you can tell them to shut up. Put one or two similar sections into the longer rides.

Week 1-2: 3x1 hour, 1x4 hours
Week 3: 3x1 hour, 1x5 hours
Week 4: 4x1 hour

**Century**
Once you are capable of a 5 hour ride, assuming that's not already century distance at your speed, you will effectively be capable of riding for 100 miles. It's just a matter of continuing to eat, drink and keep the pedals going.

**Notes**
Listen to your knees and joints. You will get more supple on the bike and you may need to get fitted again several months in. Fortunately, after that, you shouldn't change much.

Comment: Depending on progress and availability, I'd suggest looking into local group rides.  Beginner oriented rides are generally 25 KM/H, and have a "no drop" policy -- there's the chance of coaching and/or riding partners.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than targeting a C (which I assume means you want to participate in a race and be "competitive"), maybe you should consider touring instead.  Slower paced, non-competitive, emphasizes simply enjoying the ride.  Can be day trips or weeks long, road or trail, self-contained or supported, alone or in a group.

Comment: Great idea. And if you keep a log you can watch your progress (which is both a good prod and a good limiter at the same time).

Comment: I don't want to race.  When I hurt myself I was trying to build up to 100 miles for the fun of it.  But, I am certainly interested in touring.  I'd like to do a tour next summer and thought century training would get me there.

Comment: I'd recommend that you stop at a half C for now.  The problem is that beyond that you get tired and sloppy, and sloppy causes your knee to get re-injured.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are "couch to century" training plans. Depending on your problem, a century can be easier on your knee than a marathon since the maximal force during cycling is lower than during running.

[Here is a link to a typical "10-week" training plan](http://bicycling.about.com/od/trainingandfitness/a/century.htm). If you search around a bit you can find training plans from 8 weeks up to perhaps 14 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

if you're re-injuring, you have some technique problems.

number one knee strain is gear mashing, known as pushing too high a gear: 
http://adventure.howstuffworks.com/outdoor-activities/triathlons/training/mashing-vs-spinning.htm
see also sheldonbrown.com/fixed-knees.html

work on pedaling form, know as cadence and spinning, so as not to strain your knees: 
http://www.cptips.com/tech.htm

turn your bike into a trainer to keep your environment fixed while you build strength, also a training technique used by racers:
such as performancebike.com/bikes/Product_10052_10551_1111867_-1___

these fundamentals are the building blocks of any "couch to century" plan

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend getting the book "Crunch Time Cyclist" by Chris Carmichael. There is a review here for more details.

[www.roadcycling.co.nz/Coach/cycling-book-the-time-crunched-cyclist.html](http://www.roadcycling.co.nz/Coach/cycling-book-the-time-crunched-cyclist.html)

He has a specific 10 week program for novices raising their training to Century rides, but he covers so much more as well, background, nutrition etc. I'm sure you could use this to then build your own program if you want to do it over more than 10 weeks.

It worked for me, I went from a being a 10 mile commuter to a 2 day 170 mile charity rider in 8 weeks.